# onmouseout event not working with h1 tags

Tags: javascript, onmouseout

I am trying onmouseout and onmouseover events. Below code is working fine if i remove  tags, what is confusing me is , with  tags, only mouseover is firing and not mouseout. Please guide what i am doing wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div onmouseout="mouseout();" onmouseover="mouseover();" id="test"><h1> Mouse </h1> </div> 
<div id="count"> </div>
<div id="count2"> </div>
<script>
var textonout = "<h1>Mouse out</h1>";
var count =0;
var out = 0;
var textonover = "<h1>Mouse Over</h1>";
function mouseout() {

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = textonout;
document.getElementById("count2").innerHTML = out++;
}
function mouseover() {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = textonover;
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = count++;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Ok i think i understand my own question. In my case, onmouseout event doesnt fire if i have nested tags. I have tried the same code just replacing h1 tag with a div tag. I tried several combination (using span etc) as soon as i introduce any tag inside my first div, onmouseout stops working.

Can someebody guide me what is the issue ? i am not asking for the fix, i just want to understand the reason of this error.

EDIT(2). Another update, if i add the following lines, now the onmouseout event is triggering.

```
function mouseover() {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = textonover **+ count**;
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = count++;
```

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/qaA8C/1/)

**Uncaught ReferenceError: mouseout is not defined**

You had this error in your console. I admit, I prefer to seperate js and html. Call your events in your JS.

Additionally, you don't need to recreate an h1 everytime you want to change the text. Just add an id to your h1, and replace the text inside of it.

HTML:

```
<div id="test">
     <h1 id="h1"> Mouse </h1> 
</div>
<div id="count"></div>
<div id="count2"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var h1 = document.getElementById('h1');
textonout = "Mouse out";
var count = 0;
var out = 0;
var textonover = "Mouse Over";

var test = document.getElementById("test");
test.onmouseout = mouseout;
test.onmouseover = mouseover;
function mouseout() {

    h1.innerHTML = textonout;
    document.getElementById("count2").innerHTML = out++;
}

function mouseover() {
    h1.innerHTML = textonover;
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = count++;
}
```

Comment: Hi Grimbode, i turned on Firebug but i am still not seeing this error. I would appreciate if you can help me understand why mouseout wasnt triggering. Your solution works fine but i am sure i can learn from this error of mine. Please guide why mouseout event triggers without h1 tag but not with it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Follow this , it work perfect.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1 id="test"> Mouse </h1> 
<div id="count"> </div>
<div id="count2"> </div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var textonout = "Mouse out";
    var count =0;
    var out = 0;
    var textonover = "Mouse Over";
$("h1").mouseover(function(){
    $("h1").css("background-color","yellow");   
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = count++;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = textonover;
  });
  $("h1").mouseout(function(){
    $("h1").css("background-color","lightgray");
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = textonout;
    document.getElementById("count2").innerHTML = out++;
  });
  });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```